# How to use InlineKeyboardButton telegram to write inlineKeyboard?

Tags: telegram-bot

I'm trying to write inline keyboard for telegram bot. I read document but I couldn't get anything.

```
InlineKeyboardButton WeightMenu = new InlineKeyboardButton("2 Kilograms", "2");
```

I wrote this but i don't Know how can send it to user?

Why there isn't any snippet code in telegram document?
Is there any source with code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to send the inline keyboard to the user:

```
var inlineKeyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup
{
    InlineKeyboard = new []
    {
        new [] { new InlineKeyboardButton { Text = "Inline Keyboard button", CallbackData = "demo", Url = ""} }
    }
};
var newmsg = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "<b>check my new inline keyboard</b>")
{
    ReplyMarkup = inlineKeyboardMarkup,
    ParseMode = SendMessage.ParseModeEnum.HTML,DisableNotification = false,DisableWebPagePreview = false
};
WriteMessageToConsole(update.Message.Chat.Id, "_check my new inline keyboard_");
bot.MakeRequestAsync(newmsg).Wait();
```